# Add NTFS access Powershell

Tags: powershell

I was using this to make shared folder (NTFS), what am I doing wrong:
To add the access do you use `AddAccessRule()`? I was using this but it didn't work for me (no errors it just doesn't work):

```
New-Item -type directory -path C:\MyFolder
$Acl = Get-Acl "C:\MyFolder"
$Ar = New-Object system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule("username","FullControl","All‌​ow") 
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar) 
Set-Acl "C:\MyFolder" $Acl
```

Comment: Define "it just doesn't work". No permissions are set? Wrong permissions are set? Permissions look OK, but can't access the share? (Did you remember to set the SMB permissions too?)

Comment: Only the user everyone is set, if it didn't exist, but no permissions are assigned to him, and the checkbox share this folder from Advanced sharing is not checked.

Comment: @dear1, like I said in the other question, Sharing (and share permissions) are not the same as NTFS-permissions. If you want to share it too, use ex. the command in your other question first to create a share with `Everyone = FullControl` share-permissions and then modify the NTFS-Security with `Get-/Set-Acl` to limit access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution above works fine, but there's one thing to be aware of. You haven't specified any inheritance or propagation so the permissions are set on "this folder only" (not items inside). In the Security-tab it will show the user, but no permissions, but if you open Advanced you will see it has FullControl on "This folder only".

To user "normal" permissions for `This folder, subfolder and files` you need to use a different overload for `FileSystemAccessRule` that specifies inheritance. Ex:

```
$Ar = New-Object system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule("domain\username","FullControl", "ObjectInherit, ContainerInherit","None","Allow")
```

Comment: Thank you Frode, but how can I test if a user can see this if I still don't  see the checked option in Sharing > Advanced Sharing > Share this folder, what's the path I give him? I thought I needed this too to make this work completely

Comment: Read my comment on the question. Accessing a shared folder is a result of 3 things: Folder is shared ("share this folder"-checkbox"), User has SHARE Permissions (set inside Advanced Sharing -> Permissions) and user has NTFS-permissions (Security-tab, this applies both locally and through share). The most restrictive permissions of share and ntfs-permissions are the effective ones when using the share. That's why most people allow Everyone = Full Control on the share-permissions, but limit the Access using NTFS-permissions (Security tab). In other words, you still need to share the folder

Comment: And can that be done via Powershell? (Sharing folder). I see what you mean now. I used to do all of this manually in a single batch so to speak. Thanks for clearing that up for me

Comment: Yes, but you need to work with the WMI-class `Win32_Share` (for both sharing the folder and share-permissions). If you don't need any difference in permissions when local vs. remotely accessed, then you could just use `net share ..` like you did in your other question and modify the NTFS-Security afterwards to limit access. If you want to use WMI, then try google. There are many answers here on StackOverflow and other websites that explains how to use it and sharing is out-of-scope for this question.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you for all the help!